# How to populate data in a table programmatically using Docx4j API in java

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using Docx4j http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j for exporting data programmatically to a docx file. I have been successful in creating a table programmatically, but I have not been able to populate the table with values yet. The input to the table is an ArrayList of Hashmaps, for e.g.:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> objLists
```

This objLists.size will give the row count of the table and corresponding value of each key inside a hashmap will be the column data. (i.e. hashmap.keys.count == no of cols of table)

Please guide me how to add values using Docx4J APIs..

It would be great if anyone provide with a sample code to handle the same.

Answer (score 0):

Crate the Table object: tbl

Create the Table Row object:Tr

Create the Table Cell Object:Tc

Create the Text object:

Add the Text to the TableCell

Add the Table Cell to the TableRow

Add the TableRow to the Table

Add the Table to the MainDocument.

Send the request for the programatical part...